# Fastest way to create a million records in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, insert, auto-increment

what is the fastest way to create million records, where the first column is a incremental number (not a primary key) and the other fields are with their default values ?

Do I have to create a PG procedure to be faster, because it is internal i.e. does not go trough DB driver ??!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` and omit all columns that should use the default:

`insert into test(id) select generate_series(1,1000000);`

To insert the same sequence into multiple columns, you can reuse the series:

```sql
insert into test(id,id2) 
select seq,seq 
from generate_series(100,110) v(seq);
```

Comment: if i want the first TWO fields, I just add it in the query, right ??

Comment: @sten what should be in the 2nd field? the same value? a different sequence? a constant? else?

Comment: the same value as the first i.e.  test(id1,id2)

Comment: @sten see the edit, where you can generate the series only once

Comment: clever, thanks... what does v(seq) mean, have not seen this syntax ... assume it is some sort of alias

Comment: `v(seq)`:`v` is the output table alias, `seq` is the column alias.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `insert into...select...from generate_series(1,1e6)` because it is the easiest and speed is not everything, but it is not the fastest.

```
insert into foobar (id,id2) select x,x from generate_series(1,1e6) f(x);
INSERT 0 1000000
Time: 4346.187 ms (00:04.346)

copy foobar (id,id2) from program 'perl -le "print qq{\$_\t\$_} foreach 1..1_000_000"';
COPY 1000000
Time: 2720.630 ms (00:02.721)
```

Who knows, there might be something faster yet.